# Transposing every 6 row to column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i want to change every 6 row to column in Microsoft excel.

[image: every 6 rows to column convert]

want to convert like

[image: every 6 row to table]

help me how to do this?

Comment: I would record a macro - manually process the algorithm by first starting with your cursor at the top, start the recording, move one cell, move the next and the next etc. Then move back to the left, move down to the beginning of the next row, save the macro and then run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following formula:

Assuming your data is in column-A,

1. Type the following formula in cell D1
      =INDEX($A:$A,ROW(A1)*6-6+COLUMN(A1))
2. Now drag this formula up till cell I1
3. Now while the range D1:I1 is selected, drag it down till the time
   all your data is covered.

Hope this Helps.